# sql check the select return null

Tags: mysql, sql, case-when, sql-like

I want to make an query can check completely null
for example:

```
select a where
case 
    when a like %b% 
        then a like %b% (if after search every row of table still return null) 
    else
             a like %c% (if have match in any row skip else statement)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need the COALESCE() function:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a, b, c, ..., 'default')
```

this'll return the first NON-null value in the argument list, e.g.

```
COALESCE(null, null, 'hello')
```

returns `hello`.